# Set Variable to Session in Plugin. Magento2

Tags: magento2, session

is there a way to Set a Session Variable in my Plugin?

If I do something like this:

```
private $checkoutSession;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
  ){
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
  }
```

I become this Error: Type Error occurred when creating object

can someone help me?

thank you in advance.

Comment: run s:up command

Comment: it says command not found

Comment: sry I was in the wrong folder for the command. Now the command works and I think my code two. Thank you.

Comment: most welcome happy coding..:)